# Solve MiniMax optimization problem with python

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

It is possible to use the *scipy.optimize* module (*or maybe another python library*), to solve a **minimax** problem in the following form?

[image: max_y min_x (2x+2+y(-x)]

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: There's not really much to optimize here. The inner minimization problem is unbounded for y ≠ 2. For y = 2 you have max_y 2, so y = 2 is the optimal solution.

Comment: I know this is just an example, I don't know if it is possible to work with minimax on scipy. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Linear bilevel programs can be reformulated using the KKT conditions for the inner problem. The complementarity conditions can be handled for instance by a MIP model. So a linear MIP solver (readily available) would suffice (note: Scipy does not have one).

Comment: Just an addition to Erwin's comment: Scipy will have an interface to the HiGHS MILP solver soon, see [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/15294).